# How to force XML declaration tag to be sent on citrus-ws

Tags: xml, soap, citrus-framework

I'm trying to do simple soap tests with citrus-framework, but I'm unable to get the message to be accepted by the server. After some digging I found out that the xml declaration tag is not included on the message sent.

According to the log it should be sent:

```
02:06:21,600 DEBUG    xml.XmlConfigurer| Using DOMImplementationLS:
org.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDOMImplementationImpl 02:06:21,623 DEBUG
ingClientInterceptor| Sending SOAP request 02:06:21,624 DEBUG  
Logger.Message_OUT| <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/> <SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

But from the TCP/IP Monitor what I see passing through is this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

So it would be expected to be there according to the logger, but when checking what comes through the pipes it's not.

I've confirmed that what is missing is the xml declaration (<?xml version="1.0"
 encoding="UTF-8"?>), sent the same message with and without it directly to the server and with it the server processes the request, without it has the same result as when I run the citrus test (fails).

Is there any way to force it to be sent? Searched in citrus threads and spring but couldn't find a solution.

My citrus-ws conf:

```
<citrus-ws:client id="soapClient"
request-url="http://localhost:8880/WS.asmx" timeout="60000"
message-factory="soapMessageFactory"/>
```

The java dsl block:

```
soap().client("soapClient")
        .send()
        .name("testsend")
        .charset("UTF-8")
        .contentType("text/xml")
        .payload(new ClassPathResource("com/i/B.xml"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found that by default the xml declaration tag isn't sent. It is possible to send by setting WRITE_XML_DECLARATION to true<strike>, but couldn't find a way to do it through bean configuration in citrus-context.xml file</strike>.

**EDIT**: I was able to configure it through bean configuration in citrus-context.xml, explained in the end of this answer.

<s>I did, however, change it by bypassing the bean configuration file and configuring everything through POJO.</s>

<s>So here is the step by step:</s>

**POJO configuration:**

1.1. I created a class for the configuration, where I defined the bean for the message factory and set the WRITE_XML_DECLARATION to true:

```
@Bean(name = "messageFactory")
  public SaajSoapMessageFactory messageFactory() {
    SaajSoapMessageFactory smf = new SaajSoapMessageFactory();
    smf.setSoapVersion(org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_11);
    Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
    props.put(SOAPMessage.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, Boolean.toString(true));
    smf.setMessageProperties(props);
    return smf;
  }
```

1.2. On the same class I configured the bean for the soap client using the defined message factory:

```
@Bean
public WebServiceClient tClient() {
    return CitrusEndpoints.soap().client().keepSoapEnvelope(true)
                        .timeout(60000)
                        .messageFactory(messageFactory())
                        .build();
}
```

2.1. On my test class I used the *ContextConfiguration* annotation to refer to the class I created, plus *CitrusEndpoint* and *WebServiceClientConfig* annotations:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestConfig.class })
public class MyTest extends TestNGCitrusTestDesigner  {

    @CitrusEndpoint
    @WebServiceClientConfig(requestUrl = "http://localhost:8880/WS.asmx")
    private WebServiceClient soapclient;
```

2.2. And then was a matter of using the configured client:

```
 soap().client(soapclient)
.send().messageType("XML")
.name("testsend")
.payload(new ClassPathResource("com/i/B.xml"));
```

After that I confirmed that the request was sending the xml declaration tag and that the server was accepting the request.

**citrus-context.xml configuration (NEW)**:

On the citrus-context.xml, when configuring the message factory insert a property with name *messageProperties* with type *map* and insert the property *javax.xml.soap.write-xml-declaration* and set it to *true* (POJO we use *WRITE_XML_DECLARATION*, in citrus-context we use the property directly):

```
<bean id="soapMessageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
    <property name="soapVersion">
        <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_11" />
    </property>
    <property name="messageProperties">
        <util:map>
            <entry key="javax.xml.soap.write-xml-declaration" value="true"/>
        </util:map>
    </property>
</bean>
```